# Different versions of Egoroff's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have seen many versions of Egoroff's theorem which do not require that $f_k$ and $f$ to be finite a.e.. But in most of the proof, the first steps are setting $A_{i,j}=\cup_{k\geq j}\{x;|f_k(x)-f(x)| \geq 1/2^i\}$. And the set is not well-defined when $f_k$ and $f$ are infinite. Is there any proof concerning this case?

Comment: I think that what they implicitly mean is that $\vert f_k(x)-f(x)\vert =0$ if $f_k(x)=f(x)=+\infty$ while $\vert f_k(x)-f(x)\vert =+\infty$ if $f_k(x)\in\mathbb{R}, f(x)=+\infty$ or $f_k(x)=+\infty, f(x)\in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

The general proof is like this: When we say $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ pointwise a.e., we mean under the real numbers convergence.

Let $A=\{x\in X:\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}(x)=f(x)\}$, so for each $x\in A$, $f(x)$ is a real number, so there is some $n_{x}$ such that $f_{n}(x)$ is a real number for all $n\geq n_{x}$.

Now $\mu(X-A)=0$ by assumption and we let 
\begin{align*}
A_{k,m}=\bigcap_{n\geq m}\left\{x\in A:|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\dfrac{1}{k}\right\},
\end{align*}
this set $A_{k,m}$ is well defined, because it is a subset of $A$, and $f(x)$ is a real number for $x\in A$, so $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|$ is defined as an extended real number, in other words, it is not of the form $\infty-\infty$.

Now we can prove that $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\mu(X-A_{k,m})=0$ for each fixed $k$ and we are ready to derive the uniform convergence on some measurable set.

Comment: Thank you so much. But may I know that what assumption did you make ?

Comment: I am concerning if the theorem holds for $f_k$, $f$ not finite a.e.

Comment: You can look at my edited answer now.

Comment: So If $N=\{f(x)=f_k(x)=\infty\}$ (for some $k$? Or for $k \geq K$ for some $K$) has positive measure, Egoroff's theorem may fail? So sorry for late reply.

Comment: For some $k$, so which means that $N$ collects all those $|f_{k}(x)|=\infty$ or $|f(x)|=\infty$. Even though $N$ may not be of measure zero, the Egorov Theorem still works, you can re-check my proof that $N$ does not affect anything.